# A simpler way of finding all points where $g(z)=(z-3)(\overline z-3)e^{z^2}$ is holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

A simpler way of finding all points where

\begin{equation*}
g(z)=(z-3)(\overline z-3)e^{z^2}
\end{equation*}

is holomorphic? I tried the way of setting $z=x+iy$, in order to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations but got exhausted. Is there another, simpler way of doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Something to note is, that holomorphic and complex differentiable are not the same things. A function is holomorphic in a point $z_0$ if it is differentiable in some neighborhood of $z_0$. Hence, regarding the solution of ajotatxe, $g$ is only differentiable in one point, thus holomorphic nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function
$$f(z)=\frac{e^{-z^2}}{z-3}$$
for $z\neq 3$

This function is certainly holomorphic. If $g$ were holomorphic for $z\neq 3$, then $f(z)g(z)=\bar z-3$ would be holomorphic, but we know that it is not the case. Therefore, $g$ is not holomorphic for $z\neq 3$.

Let's try now to compute the derivative at $z=3$:

$$g'(3)=\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{w^2e^{{(3+w)}^2}}{w}=0$$

Nevertheless, $g$ is not holomorphic anywhere, because in order to be holomorphic, $g$ must have derivative in an open set.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Since $e^{z^2}\neq 0$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$ and $e^{z^2}$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb C$, $g$ is holomorphic in $z_0$ if and only if $(z-3)(\bar z-3)$ is holomorphic in $z_0$. Furthermore $(z-3)(\bar z-3) = |z-3|^2$. So it suffices to check, where $f(z) = |z|^2$ is holomorphic. Then $g$ is holomorphic in $z_0$ iff $f$ is holomorphic in $z_0-3$.